# C# - TransactionScope - TransactionAbortedException - The transaction has aborted

Tags: c#, transactionscope

I've code like that:

```
class Importer 
{
    private DatabaseContext m_context;

    public: Importer() 
    {
        m_context = new DatabaseContext();
        m_context.CommandTimeout = 5400; //This is seconds
    }

    public bool Import (ref String p_outErrorMsg) 
    {
        List<SomeData> dataToImport = new List<SomeData>();
        getSomeData(ref dataTiImport);

        bool result = false;

        try 
        {
            using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0))) 
            { //Two hours timeout
                result = importDatas(dataToImport);
                if (result == true) 
                {
                    scope.Complete();
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
        {
            p_outErrorMsg = String.Format("TransactionAbortedException Message: {0}", ex.Message);
        } 
        catch (ApplicationException ex) 
        {
            p_outErrorMsg = String.Format("ApplicationException Message: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    bool importDatas(List<SomeData> p_DataToImport) 
    {
        foreach (SomeData data in p_DataToImport) 
        { //There can be somehitg about 3000 iterations
            if (!importSimpleData(data)) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    bool importSimpleData(SomeData p_Data) 
    {
        //creation some object o1
        try 
        {
            m_context.objetc1s.InsertOnSubmit(o1);
            m_context.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            //Error handlig
            return false
        }

        //creation some object o2
        o2.id_o1 = o1.id_o1;
        try 
        {
            m_context.objetc2s.InsertOnSubmit(o2);
            m_context.SubmitChanges();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            //Error handlig
            return false
        }

        //creation some object o3
        o3.id_o2 = o2.id_o2;
        try 
        {
            m_context.objetc3s.InsertOnSubmit(o3);
            m_context.SubmitChanges();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            //Error handlig
            return false
        }

        //creation some object o4
        o4.id_o1 = o1.id_o1;
        try 
        {
            m_context.objetc4s.InsertOnSubmit(o4);
            m_context.SubmitChanges();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            //Error handlig
            return false
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And if List has 500 records, all is writing fine.
But when the list is near to 1000, I've always exception:
TransactionAbortedException.Message = "the transaction has aborted".

Firstly I think that timeout was to small so I did introduce to code this two lines:
...
m_context.CommandTimeout = 5400; //This is seconds (1.5 hour)
...
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0))) { //Two hours timeout
...

As you can see in presented above code.

The same exception still occurs, did I miss something?
What do I do wrongly?
I have to add that data base is remote (not local)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Instead of displaying only the exception message, could you do a complete ToString() on it? Then we would see more information.

Comment: it's not clear at the moment why you have the outer transaction scope - it seems like it would be there to roll it all back if any of them fail, but if that's what you want, just submit them all as a single transaction?  Also, if you're bulk-loading you may want to use SqlBulkCopy instead - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to dig up the documentation again, but setting a transaction timeout to 2 hours *may not be happening* for you.  There is a cap on how long the transaction timeout can be that comes down through machine.config and if you specify more than that cap, it quietly ignores you.

I ran into this a long time ago, and found a reflection-based way to tweak that setting [here by Matt Honeycutt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11314441/12484) to make sure you're really getting the timeout you specify.

Comment: Is "here" in paragraph 2 supposed to be a hyperlink -- it isn't currently?  EDIT: Found and added the link myself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that importSimpleData fails on some row and importData returns false. In such case you don't call `scope.Complete()` and it's the reason why transaction rolls back.

Comment: True, but would that raise a TransactionAbortedException?

Comment: Unfortunately every single insert: context.InsertInSubmit(...); context.SubmittChanges() were success.

Comment: @henginy You are right. What can help is to know where is exception raised. If it is during importDatas execution or during scope.Complete call.

Comment: Exception is raised during TransactionScope scope end.

Comment: @Roman see [TransactionScope.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.dispose.aspx) method.